# Identify whether the current url is http or https in a project

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, https

I have a website in Zend framework. Here I want to identify whether the current URL contains HTTPS or HTTP? I have used the following code

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS']==on){ echo "something";}else{ echo "something other";}
```

But the result is not correct. Is there is any other way to identify this?
Also I have one more question. 
How to get complete current url (including HTTP/HTTPS) using php?

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") { 
    echo "something";
} else { 
    echo "something other";
}
```

notice the `on` should be a string .

Comment: I've been looking for the same solution for a while now, but on my server I get Undefined index: HTTPS, even when I'm surfing on https

Comment: see the answer bellow, and check the port

Comment: you should check for `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` to be set before accessing it.

Comment: @Tom thanks for pointing it out, however i believe we should let users do their homework and give them only guide lines ( where possible ) that can be applied to other questions too .

Answer (score 13):

You could use methods that are already defined in Zend Framework instead of explicitly using `$_SERVER` superglobals.

To determine if the connection is HTTP or HTTPS (this code should go into your controller):

```
if ( $this->getRequest()->isSecure() ) { echo 'https'; } else { echo 'http'; }
```

To get complete current url:

```
$this->getRequest()->getScheme() . '://' . $this->getRequest()->getHttpHost() . $this->getRequest()->getRequestUri();
```

Answer (score 4):

The better way to check is

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SEREVER['HTTPS'] != 'off')
{
  //connection is secure do something
}
else
{
  //http is used
}
```

As stated in manual

> Set to a non-empty value if the script
>   was queried through the HTTPS
>   protocol.
>
> ```
> Note: Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be off if the
> ```
>
> request was not made through the HTTPS
>   protocol.

Answer (score 3):

you need to fix check it should be

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')
```

or try following function

```
if(detect_ssl()){ echo "something";}else{ echo "something other";}

function detect_ssl() {
return ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1 || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will both check if you're using https or http and output the current url.

```
$https = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off')) ? true : false;

if($https) {
    $url = "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
} else {
    $url = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}
```