# How to get the protocol in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Find Out If You are Using HTTPS Without $_SERVER['HTTPS']](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175096/how-to-find-out-if-you-are-using-https-without-serverhttps)
>   [PHP Get Site URL Protocol - http vs https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503135/php-get-site-url-protocol-http-vs-https)

How i can get the protocol in php?

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']
```

shows me the HTTP/1.1 but is there is any way to just echo http or https?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013633/identify-whether-the-current-url-is-http-or-https-in-a-project?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7431313/php-getting-full-server-name-including-port-number-and-protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$protocol = current(explode('/',$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']));
```

If you really just want to know if it HTTPS is enabled or not, you can just use `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list($protocol) = explode("/",$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']);
```